# facebook like box doesn't like the facebook page

Tags: facebook, html, iframe, facebook-likebox, xfbml

1st please don't mark my question as a duplicate one because I read all the questions related but none of the questions stated my hint.

I was trying to make a facebook like button and found that facebook like box is more what I need because it just like and doesn't show any post after like.

The idea is when I take the code from the [like box plugin link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) it doesn't add the like to the facebook page as other said that it was a bug in the facebook like. But when I press the button inside that link it will add the like to the facebook page.

The question is if it is a facebook bug should they state the first field as "Facebook Page URL" and should it work in the plugin link while you are configuring the like box before you get the code???

In other words, if it work in the plugin link so it must work if you get the code and paste it in your site, or am I wrong??

I've tried the HTML5, XFBML and IFRAME code that the facebook generate for you according to the data you provide.
No one of the below codes work; It shows the like box and when you click it will change to grey color but it doesn't make a like to the facebook page and when I refresh the test page it returns to the default state. When I was trying I found that the if I like the page from facebook site in normal way and try to dislike using the below code fro test page it will work.

**EDIT**:
While I am still trying to find a solution I found that in explorer works sometimes while in chrome and firefox doesn't.

I am using a test.html file that is placed in htdocs of xampp to test the result.

HTML5 code tried:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers" data-width="150" data-height="100" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="false" data-header="false" data-stream="false" data-show-border="false"></div>

 </body>
</html>
```

XFBML Code tried:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<fb:like-box href="http://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers" width="150" height="100" colorscheme="light" show_faces="false" header="false" stream="false" show_border="false"></fb:like-box>

 </body>
</html>
```

and the Iframe Code tried:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FFacebookDevelopers&amp;width=150&amp;height=62&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=false&amp;header=false&amp;stream=false&amp;show_border=false" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:150px; height:62px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem - have you been able to solve this in the meantime?

Comment: I was testing it on localhost. I Tried to use it on a web server and it worked without any problems.